# Error cannot find -lsbml and -lstdc++ when compiling qt project

Tags: qt, cross-compiling

I would like to cross compile a qt project on raspberry. I finished all the installing steps and the configuration of qt creator. But when i tried but when i tried to compile an example project I got an error

```
cannot find -lsbml
cannot find -lstdc++
```

Answer (score 0):

First make sure that these libs are already installed:

```
sudo apt-get install sbml
sudo apt-get install stdc++
```

I am not sure about the names, but you can check them via apt-cache like:

```
apt-cache search sbml | less
```

You can use this to get all packages which are related to the corresponding library. Choose the right package and install it via **apt-get install ...**

Now try again. When the compile-step still fails you need to specify the lib-directories in the .pro-file like:

```
LIBS += -L<Path_to_sbml> -lsbml -L<Path_to_stdc++> -lstdc++
```

Hope that helps you.